# Facebook apprequests are now show in app center and not in notifications

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-app-requests

We send facebook user to user apprequests from ios app. Earlier they appear in notification section on users facebook page, but now they begin to appear in app center->requests section. Users do not notice them.

Facebook app is configured as Website with Facebook Login and Native iOS App.

How can we switch back to previous behaviour?

Comment: Is the receiving user a user of your app already? Otherwise, the request is considered an "invite", and those are distributed differently. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/requests/ "Facebook separates out invites from other requests and showcases them separately on the Games Dashboard."

Comment: we tried sending to different users, some of them have our others don't, and all requests are shown in app center