# Requests go to App Center -> Requests instead of to Notifications

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I would like to post a Request which will show up in facebook.com's Notifications section and in the iOS native app's Notifications section (the world icon). Instead, my Request shows up in the recipient's "App Center" under that "Requests" section, which makes me think this request is being treated as an invitation to try this app. Both the sender and the recipient are "is_app_user=1"; they are both app users.

```
[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:FBSession.activeSession
    message:@"message"
    title:@"title"
    parameters:nil
    handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
}];
```

I'm receiving a response which looks like everything worked:

```
(lldb) p result
(FBWebDialogResult) $1 = FBWebDialogResultDialogCompleted
(lldb) po resultURL
$2 = 0x24cbdb30 fbconnect://success?request=206296506185732&to%5B0%5D=[TO_FBID]
(lldb) po error
$3 = 0x00000000 <nil>
```

Notes:

- We marked the app as Category "Game" in our https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[APP_ID]/appdetails
- We entered our "iPhone App Store ID"
- This Facebook app is in "sandbox mode" because it hasn't been released yet
- We don't have a Canvas URL since we're a solely native mobile game
- I believe this question [Facebook apprequests are now show in app center and not in notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888949/facebook-apprequests-are-now-show-in-app-center-and-not-in-notifications) is related, but it has no answers.

How can we get this Request to show up in the Notifications section?